# How did Maxwell determine that the divergence of a magnetic field is zero?

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations, history

Was this equation the result of experimentation and the equation just describes what is found or was the equation, for example, derived mathematically and it then showed that the divergence was zero?

Comment: <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_law_for_magnetism#History> – It is not a mathematical necessity but an observational fact about nature. See also <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_monopole#Maxwell's_equations>